# Change plot background color in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook

How can I change the grey color in the background to white color?

```
mydata.plot()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Please share your current code and the library you use to create the plot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 10, .1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.figure(facecolor='yellow')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel("X")
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_facecolor("violet")
plt.ylabel('sin(x)')
plt.show()
```

it make it yellow my freind